# Can't access my WordPress website after changing the domain name at domain/ WP-admin

Tags: wordpress, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, domain-name

Basically, I was in charge of changing the domain of a WordPress site. While doing some testing, I ended up changing the domain in mydomain/wp-admin and now I'm getting the following error whenever I try to access the site:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syx2X.png)

Also, I can't access the wp-admin page either. Whenever I try it, I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwaEn.png)

Since I have almost no experience with these tools (wordpress, docker, ubuntu), I don't know what to do. My goal is just to reverse this domain change and go back to the old.

To try to solve this problem I already tried some things:

- Inside the server, in **home/ubuntu/site-docker/src**, I already changed the wp-config.php file and added **define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://mydomain' )** and **define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://mydomain' )**;
- In **home/ubuntu/site-docker/src/wp-content/themes**, I already entered the folders of all themes (since I didn't remember which theme I was using) and changed the **functions.php** file, adding **update_option('siteurl', 'https://mydomain')** and **update_option('home', 'https://mydomain')**;

In the end, nothing really worked.

Answer (score 0):

First I can't reach links you sent. Did you replace your old website domain in your database with new domain address?

Comment: I haven't changed it yet but I don't know how either. How should I access the database?
I only have access to the server through ssh terminal and FileZilla.